# gdb does not hit any breakpoints when I run it from inside Docker container

Tags: linux, debugging, permissions, docker, gdb

**The problem**

I am able to set and reach a breakpoint if I compile and run from the host, but if I do it from within the docker container gdb does not hit the breakpoints that were set.

**Steps to reproduce (all snippets are copy-paste ready)**

Create a docker file:

```
cat << EOF > Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential gdb
EOF
```

Build an image and run an interactive session in it:

```
docker build -t gdb_problem_testing . && docker run --rm -it  gdb_problem_testing bash
```

From inside of the container create small main.cpp, compile, and run gdb:

```
cat <<EOF > main.cpp && g++ -g main.cpp && gdb -ex 'break 5' -ex 'run' ./a.out
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "hi\n";
    return 0;
}
EOF
```

Observe the gdb output:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
[Skipped gdb greeting]
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40078c: file main.cpp, line 5.
1   #include <iostream>
2   
3   int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
4   {
5       std::cout << "hi\n";
6       return 0;
7   }
Starting program: /a.out 
hi
During startup program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

From the output one can see that the breakpoint was not hit, although the program was executed (printed 'hi') and exited successfully. I guess the most important thing here is that the program did run and that the message **During startup program exited normally** is an anomalous behavior (according to [GDB ignores my breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809174/gdb-ignores-my-breakpoints) )

**Question**

What is preventing gdb from setting the breakpoint and how to fix this?

**What I tried so far**

1. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586086/gdb-problems-inside-docker), I tried to change a line in `/etc/apparmor.d/docker` (I did it in the host):
   substitute `profile docker-default flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted) {` by `profile docker-default flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted,complain) {`. Then run the docker container, compile, and gdb. The result was the same: `During startup program exited normally`.
2. As suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809174/gdb-ignores-my-breakpoints),  from within the container, I tried to do `strace -f -o syscall.txt gdb ./a.out`, but I get the following error:

   ```
   strace: test_ptrace_setoptions_followfork: PTRACE_TRACEME doesn't work: Permission denied
   strace: test_ptrace_setoptions_followfork: unexpected exit status 1
   ```

   but I do not understand how to work this around. I tried to start the container as root: `sudo docker run --rm -it  gdb_problem_testing bash` and then tried the strace -- this gave me the same error. I must admit I do not understand how the user privileges are managed by the docker, i.e. what user rights the root inside of the container has and from whom does it inherit the rights (from the docker daemon?). Since I able to hit the breakpoint, when I run gdb in the host, I suspect that my problem would boil down to the user rights, but I do not know how to approach it.
3. In the host I tried to do `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` as suggested in yet [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process).

Comment: What is your host OS (distro and kernel version)? We can try to reproduce the error. Your example works fine - gdb successfully stops at line 5 - on vanilla, fully-patched versions of Ubuntu 15.04 and 14.04.3 x86_64 using the docker image of Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving it a try. The fact that it works for you gives me a completely different perspective on this.
My host OS is Ubuntu. $ uname -a
Linux LT0377 3.19.0-42-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:24:49 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I do not understand what version of Ubuntu do I have in the docker image. If I do uname -a inside of the container I get the same output as in the host.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Could you tell me what is your Docker version?

Comment: I used the version of docker that came in the Ubuntu repositories. On both 14.04.3 and 15.04, it was `Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2`.

Comment: The `ubuntu` image in docker's repository appears to be 14.04.3; I was wrong about it being 14.04.2.

Comment: Thank you, @Mark Plotnick. My docker --version is 1.9.1, build a34a1d5.

Comment: I have installed the latest Ubuntu updates. My version is now $ uname -a
Linux LT0377 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 16:09:14 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

The problem is still there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

update 2020.01.04: Use the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530095) given by [Kevin W Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8807809/kevin-w-matthews) --- it's better because it grants the necessary individual capabilities without elevating the entire container.

---

tldr; use

```
docker run --privileged
```

Longer: I was having some [problems with gdb in docker](https://rubicks.github.io/post/docker-run-privileged-gdb/)---it was attempting (and failing) to disable [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)---but only on `docker-machine`, not on my native linux host.

When gdb failed to disable ASLR, all of my breakpoints would be ignored. Using the `--privileged` flag fixed my issue. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately I cannot test it anymore, since I do not have access to this environment. In case anyone else finds your solution helpful, I would accept it as an answer.

Comment: This helped me. It was baffling why no endpoints where being hit, but then  running the container with --privileged worked!. I can now use gdb properly inside my container

Comment: Also helped me! Within docker, one may need to commit current container into a new image, then `docker rm <container-name/id>`,  then start a new container (with `--privileged`) based on the new committed image to restart the job.

Comment: i faced this problem today, and the --privileged argument solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than elevating the entire container, I was able to use the option

```
--security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

to fix address space randomization problems.

Some also recommend enabling the `ptrace` capability with

```
--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE
```

but this didn't seem to have any effect for me.

Here are the same settings for Docker compose:

```
security_opt:
  - seccomp:unconfined
cap_add:
  - SYS_PTRACE
```

Details are taken from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676907/8807809).

Comment: This answer is better than mine. I'm editing mine to reference yours.

Answer (score 1):

thanks the answer from @rubicks.

and if you can't use `--privileged` option(e.g. you are using a container from cloud), you can print stacktrace from your program:

[How to automatically generate a stacktrace when my gcc C++ program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-program-crashes/77336#77336)