# warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted

Tags: c, docker, gdb

what have i done wrong (or didn't do) that `gdb` is not working properly for me?

```
root@6be3d60ab7c6:/# cat minimal.c 
int main()
{
  int i = 1337;
  return 0;
}
root@6be3d60ab7c6:/# gcc -g minimal.c -o minimal
root@6be3d60ab7c6:/# gdb minimal
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
.
.
.
Reading symbols from minimal...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004f1: file minimal.c, line 3.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /minimal 
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
During startup program exited normally.
(gdb) 
(gdb) print i   
No symbol "i" in current context.
```

Comment: When running within a docker container, I got this error until I added`--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` to the `docker run`.

Comment: @CameronTaggart thanks for the tip! You made my day.

Comment: @CameronTaggart  it works good for me, but security problem coms

Answer (score 186, accepted):

If you're using Docker, you probably need the `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` option (as well as enabling ptrace):

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

Comment: thanks for this - I've no idea how much time I'd've lost learning this the hard way!

Comment: I think `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` is only needed when attaching `gdb` to an already running process.

Comment: Could you provide the security issues using these options might involve ?

Comment: Is there a way to apply this command to an already running instance? Because I don't want to remove this instance and start a new one

Comment: Hmm Doesn't work for me.  I get `warning: Could not trace the inferior process.
warning: ptrace: Permission denied` What I'm doing is`docker create --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined -it blah`  followed by `docker start -i blah`  ... seems this should have worked!?

Answer (score 21):

For whatever reason, your user account doesn't have permission to disable the kernel's address space layout randomisation for this process. By default, gdb turns this off because it makes some sorts of debugging easier (in particular, it means the address of stack objects will be the same each time you run your program). Read more [here](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_disable-randomization).

You can work around this problem by disabling this feature of gdb with `set disable-randomization off`.

As for getting your user the permission needed to disable ASLR, it probably boils down to having write permission to `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`. Read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization).

Answer (score 17):

Building on [wisbucky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676907/8807809) (thank you!), here are the same settings for Docker compose:

```
security_opt:
  - seccomp:unconfined
cap_add:
  - SYS_PTRACE
```

The security option `seccomp:unconfined` fixed the `address space randomization` warnings.

The capability SYS_PTRACE didn't seem to have a noticeable effect even though the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) states that SYS_PTRACE is a capability that is "not granted by default". Perhaps I don't know what to look for.

Comment: YOu have a typo, it is unconfined not unconfirmed