# Visual Studio Code errors when debugging Rust with "Missing auto-load debug_gdb_scripts"

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger

I installed flatpak Visual Studio Code on Linux Mint. I'm trying to debug the "Hello world app" from the Rust book in VS Code.

**src/main.rs**:

```rust
fn main() {
  println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

**launch.json**:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
   {
    "name": "Debug program",
    "type": "gdb",
    "request": "launch",
    "target": "../target/debug/hello",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I `cargo build` the program and try to debug it, I get this error in Debug console:

```
warning: Missing auto-load script at offset 0 in section .debug_gdb_scripts
of file /home/gorn/nextcloud/viptrader/rust/target/debug/hello.
Use `info auto-load python-scripts [REGEXP]' to list them.
Running executable
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
```

I have installed these extensions:

- rust-lang.rust
- [webfreak.debug](https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug)

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is the `Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted`. The `Missing auto-load script` warning you can usually ignore.

The problem is likely caused by virtualization.

Try adding [`set disable-randomization off`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860616/257568) into the [`.gdbinit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gdbinit.5.html).

You might also follow this [flatpak issue 1301](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1301).

Comment: Parto of the error seems to disappear when I put the `.gdbinit` into home directory, however the debugign still does not work - the script gets executed, but for example breakpoints are not functional etc.

Comment: Okay, let's hope `flatpak` users will stop by and add more. Are you using [`--devel`](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/debugging.html)?