# LLDB producing 'A packet returned error 8' when I run my program

Tags: c++, lldb, clang++

I've been trying to locate where a segmentation fault is in a program using LLDB. I've been going to the Ubuntu shell on [repl.it](http://repl.it) and compiling my code using `clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp -g` and the program compiles succesfully. Next, I run `lldb main` and everything's fine but as soon as I type `run` I get `error: process launch failed: 'A' packet returned an error: 8`. I've checked the docs and looked up the error but I can't seem to find anything. Thanks for any sort of help!

The full log:

```
~/Project$ clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp -g
~/Project$ lldb main
(lldb) target create "main"
Current executable set to 'main' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
error: process launch failed: 'A' packet returned an error: 8
```

In case you need the code it's on this Github: https://github.com/KingsleyDockerill/Wirth

Comment: Are you by any chance using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Comment: @dfrib I do not think I am. I'm using the website repl.it and it's console so there's  chance

Comment: Sounds like an environment issue: e.g. [this post](https://replit.com/talk/ask/C-debugging/17260) on repl.it mentions exactly the same lldb error, and one answer questions whether repl.it supports debugging with lldb and/or gdb.

Comment: The error means that the debugger wasn't allowed to launch the process for debugging.  Make sure the process launches outside the debugger, but if it does, then likely debugging is the issue.  IIRC as a security measure, you can configure Linux systems to allow debugging or to not allow debugging.  At some point, for instance, the default for Docker images was to NOT allow debugging, though I don't know if that's still true.  You might check to make sure the system you are using is set up to allow debugging.

Comment: Those coming here from Google - If you are running on docker, [this is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108776/913098)

Answer (score 9):

For those using `Docker`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108776/11720321), they need to add `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined` to their `docker run` command in order to use `lldb`.

for [devcontainer](https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json) add these properties

```json
{
  "capAdd": ["SYS_PTRACE"],
  "securityOpt": ["seccomp=unconfined"]
}
```

See also [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676907/11720321).