# gdb exits immediately `Process finished with exit code 1` or lldb `'A packet returned error 8'` on docker. Also: How to allow c++ debugging in docker

Tags: c++, docker, debugging

This took me full days to find, so I am posting this for future reference.

I am developing C++ on a docker image. I am using clion.
My code is compiled in debug mode, and runs fine in run mode, but when trying to debug, the process exits immediately with the very informative

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

When switching the debugger from
[image]

to

[image]

Trying to debug still exits, but yields a popup in clion

```
'A packet returned error 8'
```

The same code debugs fine on a local computer.

The `docker run` command is

```
RUN_CMD="docker run --group-add ${DOCKER_GROUP_ID} \
                --env HOME=${HOME} \
                --env="DISPLAY" \
                --entrypoint /bin/bash \
                --interactive \
                --net "host" \
                --rm \
                --tty \
                --user=${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID} \
                --volume ${HOME}:${HOME} \
                --volume /mnt:/mnt \
                $(cat ${HOME}/personal-uv-docker-flags) \
                -v "${HOME}/.Xauthority:${HOME}/.Xauthority:rw" \
                --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
                --workdir ${HOME} \
                ${IMAGE} $(${DIR}/impl/known-tools.py cmd-line ${TOOL})"
```

---

How to debug C++ on docker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually, I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291157/lldb-producing-a-packet-returned-error-8-when-i-run-my-program#comment122522595_69291157) which led me to [this blog post](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Debug-CPP-In-Docker-Container/), in which I learned C++ debugging is disallowed on docker by default.

> The arguments --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE and --security-opt
> seccomp=unconfined are required for C++ memory profiling and debugging
> in Docker.

I added

```
--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

to the `docker run` command, and the debugger was able to connect.

Comment: I don't think this works on Apple M1: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5191#issuecomment-821319621