# Operation not permitted when gdb tries to disable address space randomization

Tags: gdb, aslr

My question is similar to this problem: [warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860527/warning-error-disabling-address-space-randomization-operation-not-permitted)

Except, I am not using docker but google colab(Ubuntu 18.04.3).
So, the solution does not seem to work for me.
Based on the site, colab uses Ubuntu 18.04.3. So, set disable-randomization should work. Yet, it gives error as the section below:

```
(gdb) file test
Reading symbols from test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) show disable-randomization 
Disabling randomization of debuggee's virtual address space is on.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /content/test 
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
```

Is there a way I can run the code with ASLR disabled in gdb?

I have tried running `!echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` and then setting disable-randomization off too, but it still displays the same `warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted`.